# Python convention for variable naming to indicate units

Tags: python, naming-conventions, pep8

First, when I ask about units I mean units of measurement like inches, feet, pixels, cells.  I am not referring to data types like int and float.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation) refers to this as **logical data type** rather than **physical data type**.

I'd like to know the best way to name variables.

Here is some code to walk through what I'm asking:

```
board_length=8 #in inches
board_length=8*12 #Convert from feet to inches
```

Notice that these are both integers (or floats, I don't care), yet I’ve changed units.  I’ve also kept the variable name the same.  I could establish a convention, and that’s the purpose of this question.  Without guidance, I might do something like this:

```
board_length=8
board_length_inches=8*12
```

I would consider this an ad-hoc way of doing things.  Or, I might establish a convention:

```
Fboard_length=8
Iboard_length=8*12
```

Or other variants that I equally dislike.  How might I name variables in a descriptive way, yet stay as close to [PEP-08](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) as possible?

Just to be as clear as I can, the variables may have different data types, yet the units would be the same (inches would have the same naming regardless of if it was stored as and integer or a float)

Comment: Depending on how much the units matter to your script, you could consider making type sub-classes based on each unit.  Each "unit of measure" (length, weight, etc.) would have its on class that inherits the  built-in types, and has its own sub-classes for the individual units.  These units would then have methods for converting to all other units of the same type.  This would be a lot of work, so you need to ask if its really worth it

Comment: Or you could decorate the builtins to have an attribute or method which keeps track of units

Comment: I wouldn't worry about this too much. I can't think of any cases where you would need to store the same value in different units for sustained periods of time. I would just do this - `board_length = 24    # in inches` (several lines later) `print(to_feet(board_length))`, or `FEET = 12; print(board_length*FEET)`.

Comment: I use `board_length_inches` in cases like this. Keep it simple.

Comment: I'm with @sweeneyrod. To put it another way, your strategy should be to pick some unit that you'll use internally for all calculations, and just use that consistently. You would only be concerned about conversion between different units when interfacing (either with a human user, or with some module that needs units other than what you are using), and you'd use aptly named conversion functions or methods at those interface points in your code.

Comment: @john y, consider the case where I have cartesian coordinates specified in (Xn, Yn) and want to map those points to a 2D matrix (Mn, Nn).  usually the process is to convert from one reference system to another, do something, then convert back to the original.  This process happens to different variables at different times in the code.  In practice, I've been using a suffix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd go further and have separate object types providing type safety rather than simply rely on naming conventions. Otherwise you could pass a variable representing inches into a method requiring miles.

I think that relying on naming conventions is going to be problematic to maintain long term and making use of types will give you much more flexibility and safety (e.g. providing conversions etc. built into the object types)

Comment: This is sound advice.  If the purpose for a naming convention is to help the developer avoid confusion & mistakes -- you will get a lot further by letting the Python class system enforce the rules for you. If you use a naming convention only, a confused developer could easily do things like 12 (inches) + 1 (cm) = 13 (oops).

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer even though it doesn't suggest a naming convention, it does suggest an alternative that would work for others interested in this question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

While you could come up with a naming convention, you might be better served by building an object representing "distance" with properties to read/write in different units.  For instance:

```
class Distance(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._inches = 0

    @property
    def inches(self):
        return self._inches

    @inches.setter
    def inches(self, value):
        self._inches = value

    @property
    def feet(self):
        return self._inches/12

    @feet.setter
    def feet(self, value):
        self._inches = value * 12
```

You could even make it more generic, so that you could easily extend with new conversions.  (Note: Edited this to memoize based upon comments)

```
from collections import defaultdict

class Distance(object):

    _conversion_map = defaultdict(lambda: {'to' : None, 'from' : None})

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self._memo = {}
        if kwargs:
            unit, value = kwargs.iteritems().next()
            if unit == 'inches':
                self.inches = value
            else:
                setattr(self, unit, value)
        else:
            self.inches = 0

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self._conversion_map:
            try:
                return self._memo[name]
            except KeyError:
                converter = self._conversion_map[name]['to']
                if converter is None:
                    raise AttributeError
                converted = converter(self.inches)
                self._memo[name] = converted
                return converted
        else:
            raise AttributeError

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == '_memo':
            super(Distance, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        else:
            # Clear memoized values if setting the value of the object
            self._memo = {}
        if name == 'inches':
            super(Distance, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        if name in self._conversion_map:
            converter = self._conversion_map[name]['from']
            if converter is None:
                raise AttributeError
            self._memo[name] = value
            self.inches = converter(value)
        else:
            raise AttributeError

    @classmethod
    def converter(cls, func):
        direction, unit = func.__name__.split('_', 1)
        cls._conversion_map[unit][direction] = func
        return func

@Distance.converter
def to_feet(value):
    return value / 12

@Distance.converter
def from_feet(value):
    return value * 12

board_1_length = Distance(feet=2)
board_2_length = Distance(inches=14)
board_1_length.inches # 24
board_2_length.feet # 1 (integer division)
```

Comment: For my application, I am less inclined to use this technique (although possible).  The flaw was in my overly-simple example.  The issue is that conversion between units is slow and essentially one way...in my particular case it would be representing shapes as vector data some times and as a field of grey scale in others (ie SVG versus BMP).

Comment: You could combine this sort of pattern with a caching system, so the full conversion is only done the first time (though still lazily), then the cached converted structure is returned thereafter.

Answer (score 4):

...six years later...

Long after my question, I stumbled on the python typing library.  It provides a (runtime) free method of static type checking a variable more specifically than just "int" or "float" but instead "inches" and "meters":

```
from typing import NewType

UserId = NewType('UserId', int)
some_id = UserId(524313)
```

This gets me most of what I was after.

Comment: You mention units like inches and meters, but where in your example or on https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html is that mentioned?

Answer (score 3):

If you want more robust unit support, you should check out [PyPi's Pint module](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Pint/).  It doesn't directly deal with your question of naming convention, but it can take a lot of the work out of dealing with frequent conversions.  You can find info on it and some other unit modules here:

http://www.drdobbs.com/jvm/quantities-and-units-in-python/240161101

Comment: I like this suggestion generally and it seems like a good way to essentially implement what @BrianAgnew suggested.